# Eclipse cannot find class com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken?

Tags: eclipse, maven, guava, google-cloud-dataflow

My project which uses Dataflow compiles just fine using

```
mvn compile
```

However when I import my project into eclipse, eclipse is unable to build the project and gives the following error

```
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. 
Cannot find the class file for com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken. 
Fix the build path then try building this project
```

Comment: Is the Eclipse project configured to be handled by Maven? I.e. does it have a small 'M' on the project icon?

Answer (score 5):

Adding an explicit dependency on Guava to my pom file appears to have fixed the problem.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>[18.0,)</version>
</dependency>
```

By running

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=com.google.guava
```

I learned that I had several dependencies that were pulling in Guava so by adding an explicit dependency I was able to force maven to pull in a newer version.

However, I don't know why running 'mvn compile' on the command line worked.